# Would like to implement letters in encryption program

Tags: c, encryption

---

I am writing a very, very basic encryption device.  It's not meant to outwit the NSA, but just for fun.  So far, it handles numbers just fine(it's just multiplying by a large prime number).  However, is there a way to convert a letter or word into a number, that can be converted back to its original form(keep in mind that encryption isn't worth much without decryption)?  Here's the code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int x,y,z;
int encrypt_number[] = {7507,55529,77933,142867,392263};
printf("\tCaleb's encryption machine\n\n");
printf("Please enter your number\n");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("Enter your encryption key number between one and five\n");
scanf("%d",&y);
if (y == 1)
y = encrypt_number[0];
else if ( y == 2 )
y = encrypt_number[1];
else if ( y == 3 )
y = encrypt_number[2];
else if ( y == 4 )
y = encrypt_number[3];
else if ( y == 5 )
y = encrypt_number[4];
else
printf("not a valid option\n");
z = x*y;
printf("Your encrypted, safer than average, number is: %d\n",z);
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this but not all of them are "secure". For example, you can cast a `char*` to an `int*` and simply interpret four characters as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

To your question: Is there a way to convert a letter or word into a number, that can be converted back to its original form(keep in mind that encryption isn't worth much without decryption)?

The answer is deceptively simple: It's called character sets/code pages/character encoding.
Unless you want something more restricted and more space-efficient, in which case you must decide on which symbols you support and then manually assign each a number.

You should have no problems doing that, as a C `char` is just a small number. There's just one caveat: You actually want explicitly `unsigned char` or `signed char`, otherwise the implementation decides for you.
Look in the `<stdlib.h>`-header for character -set conversion.
For reference, use [C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

yep, convert the letter from ascii to decimal.

```
char c='B';
int decimalRep=c;
printf("The char. %c in Decimal is:%i",c,decimalRep);
```

**output: The char. B in Decimal is:66**

Comment: Oh, wow!  Okay, I should have thought of that.  Much appreciated.  Now when it is decrypted, you would divide it by the key it was encrypted with and then turn that quotient into its ascii letter.

Answer (score 0):

Played with it a bit.  Came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int encrypt(
      int  I__value,
      int  I__key,
      int *_O_valueEncrypted
      )
   {
   int rCode=0;
   int encrypt_number[] = {7507,55529,77933,142867,392263};

   if((I__key < 1) || (I__key > 5))
      {
      rCode = ERANGE;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   *_O_encryptedValue = I__value * encrypt_number[I__key-1];

CLEANUP:     

   return(rCode);  
   }

int main()
   {
   char inputBuffer[255+1];  

   printf("\tCaleb's encryption machine\n\n");
   printf("Please enter your message to encrypt:\n");
   fgets(inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer), stdin);

   printf("Enter your encryption key number between one and five\n");
   scanf("%d", &y);

   printf("Your encrypted, safer than average, message = \"");
   for(i=0; i<strlen(inputBuffer); ++i)
      {
      int y,z;

      rCode=encrypt(inputBuffer[i], y, &z);
      switch(rCode)
         {
         case 0: 
            break;

         case ERANGE:    
            fprintf(stderr, "Key number is out of range.\n");
            goto CLEANUP;
         }

      printf("%s%d", i ? "," : "", z);
      }

   printf("\"\n");

   return(0);
   }
```

(Might have errors.  I didn't try to compile it)